# Convert html to rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, html-helper, helper

I am a RoR developer. I work with a graphic designer who prepares **static html/css** files and forward them to me.

Then I covert those html code to haml and include them in my views.

I use http://html2haml.heroku.com/ to covert html to haml. But it doesn't covert to haml using **Rails helpers**.

Example:

It converts

```
<img src="abc.png" />
```

To

```
%img{:src => "abc.png"}/
```

But I need it to be converted to

```
=image_tag "abc.png"
```

The same for other Rails helpers (link_to, text_field, ...etc)

Is there anything can make my work easier and converts using helpers?

Answer (score 0):

I think, there's only one solution to this: your views should be built with Rails helpers from its beginning. There's many tools that can help create static views (which become your project views then), such as [Serve](http://get-serve.com/documentation/rails-prototyping-tutorial) or [Middleman](http://middlemanapp.com/). The downside is that your designer should know about Rails helpers, haml etc, but this is a classical tradeoff.